# Приват24 API крашится при возврате merchanID

Tags: ios, objective-c

Работаю с API Приват24.

Просит мерчант ID. Метод датасорса возвращает строку, я ему ее подкидываю. Приложение падает.

```
- (NSString *)oneClickPayMerchantID {
NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

NSString *merchantID = @"297100146db1ee6c88afd892cdcf2d10";
return merchantID;

//[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)merchantID.UTF8String];
}
```

Перепробовал много вариантов. Результата - 0.

Ошибка во время краша приложения:

```
-[PayViewController oneClickPayMerchantID]
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x183b8022c 0x1958540e4 0x183b8016c 0x18498e5c8 0x10058b900 0x10058b0fc 0x18353fb14 0x184a671c4 0x1849b8604 0x1849a81cc 0x184a69f28 0x100f74f94 0x100f79c28 0x183b37544 0x183b355ec 0x183a60f74 0x18d4bb6fc 0x188662d94 0x100092198 0x195efea08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Так вы бы у приватовской техподдержки и спросили.

Comment: Они меня посылают из одного ресурса на другой, и так уже третий день. Концов не могу найти.

Comment: побольше бы информации. NSLog я так понимаю срабатывает?

Comment: @iSerg: Ну так объясните им, что кагбе вы пишете приложуху для их клиентов, и что это в их и Игоря Валерьевича интересе, чтобы у вас всё получилось. Пусть выведут вас на разрабов.

Comment: а вот, допустим накопал такой метод: `-(void)oneClickFailedWithError:(NSError *)error;`, пишут, что должен выводить все ошибки. пробовали такое?

Comment: да. Крашится при выходе с метода. В oneClickFailedWithError даже не заходит. Заюзал их старую библиотеку, но там тоже oneClickFailedWithError выдает ошибку (о том что не введен номер телефона, но и тогда же не срабатывает метод который возвращает в либу номер телефона), когда хочу получить список карт юзера. Короче весело. И гайдов толком никаких, просто описание ошибок.

Comment: включите exception breakpoints, может там какая то информация проскочит